# Did Java FX2 fail?

Tags: java, architecture, javafx-2, javafx

I am learning Java, and I am planning to develop a property management software for Windows.

I need to build the architecture for the program, and I am thinking of learning some technology for it.

I am considering Java FX 2.x, since I am also interested in web or mobile development.

However, there does not seem to be many Java FX 2.x books available at this time, while it has been quite a long time since JavaFX 2 has been released.

What is the problem? Is it not successful?

Also, is learning JavaFX 2.x recommended for me to develop the office software relatively easily?

Comment: What do you mean by fail?

Comment: Not successful? When some new technology comes out, plenty of books and manuals are available after a few months. This is not the case when it comes to Java FX 2. I thought it was strange.

Comment: In my opinion JavaFx is an under-utilized architecture. I learned it, used it but as of a few months ago it still was not supported on Mac. I'd have to check again, but the simple fact that it isn't supported on all systems (only the newer ones) means its not an option for business.

Comment: @SyntaxRules Then what should I use?

Comment: @user2418202 That is a great question, the answer depends on what you want done as all the technologies have pro's and con's. Becasue you want this comparable with web applications I'd suggest looking at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2055564/1767377) and seeing if any of these look like they might fit your needs. Best of luck!