# what are the steps to make a word search for a website?

Tags: java, search, search-engine, web-crawler, keyword-search

I want to write a word search,which connects to a specific website(huge one),takes the word from user,searches the site and returns the strings which contain the word;this should be written in java and as an applet.I have read some tutorials and questions on this,and understood what have to be done is:

1.connect to a website and get the content of a website and save it to a string.(this should be done with a webcrawler which will be made from my own code for connecting to website and save the content to a string + jsoup library to parse the html code).

2.save the datas to a database(in my case nosql database).

3.index the datas in database.

4.query the database to show the results.

5.make a UI for showing the search results(I use swing.japplet).

now my qustions are:

1.have I understood correctly the steps which I have to go?(please explain me in details if a step is unnecessary or necessary)

2.Is it necessary to have a database?

notice:I want to implement it myself,without using ready things such as lucene,nutch,solr,...

edit:3 people told me applet is not suitable for such a thing,so what should be the replacement?

many many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using Lucene, as it does most of what you want here.

You should not use applets.

Comment: no I want to implement it myself.not by ready things such as lucene,why not applets?

Comment: @user2841094 - I've explained why applets are a bad idea in my Answer.

Comment: what should it be instead of an applet?a web service?

Answer (score 0):

For small data set, database should be sufficient. Databases like mysql comes with [full text search functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html).

For bigger data set, you might want to consider [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/) or [Solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: you mean I should use mysql instead of nosql databases?

Comment: if i were you, i will just go with solr.

Answer (score 0):

That is one way way to implement this.  Another (simpler) way would be to use an existing text search / indexing engine like Lucene / Solr.  Going to the effort of reimplementing the "text search / indexing" wheel using database technology strikes me as a waste of effort, unless you have a sound technical reason for doing so.

You do need to has some kind of database, because indexing a website on the fly would simply not work.  Lucene will handle that.

I think your choice of Java applets to build the UI is a bad idea.  There are other technologies that give results that are as good or better ... without the security risk of a Java browser plugin.

---

Finally, another way to make your website searchable is to get Google to do it for you.  Make your website content indexable, and then use Google's search APIs.

Comment: can me guide me with better technologies,please?

Comment: Start by looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055430/list-of-rich-web-application-technologies