# Ideas for a C# UI framework

Tags: c#, flash, user-interface, frameworks, integrate

I need to develop a C# touch-screen desktop application with a "modern good-looking" UI.
How would you approach it? I´ve got in mind using Flash (just for the UI) or WPF... but i´m open to any idea or any third-party C# UI you´d know.
Is Flash easy to integrate with C#?

Thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: just wait for window 8 and Metro Style application :-)

Comment: Just google'd this, looks very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a AMF remoting library in C#.

- Remoting is when you call a function on your server from flash.
- AMF (version 0 or 3) is a binary format used to encode object transfered
  between client and server

Weborb and fluorine are solutions for this.
see : [.NET and AMF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78477/net-and-amf)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably be doing well with a third party framework to avoid the overhead of writing user interactions, controls, etc.

A couple of options are

- http://xamarin.com/
- http://www.resco.net/developer/mobileformstoolkit/

A review of these options is provided [here](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-for-mobile-development.html).

Comment: "Speed up the mobile development by over 45%". Huh? I've expected at least over 46%!

Answer (score 0):

I recall combining a flash interface with a C# back-end back in university. There's a method called fscommand() that will take a couple of string parameters (I may be mistaken, read up on it) to pass to and from the interface and the C# "code-behind".Flash is an ok option, but if I were you I'd opt for a WPF interface. I'm a huge fan of the telerik libraries, their WPF one allows you to create the most modern-looking interfaces and dashboards. Not to mention that the skills you will acquire while learning enough about wpf will be hugely beneficial in your career as a developer the way things are going (depending, obviously, on what direction you're heading).

Comment: fscommand() has been replaced by ExternalInterface, most commonly used for calls between ActionScript and JavaScript in a web page, but it can also be used between ActionScript and C#, and is pretty easy to work with: http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/tag/external-interface/

Answer (score 0):

FlashBuilder 4.6 has some nice functionality for quickly building a UI that work on a desktop or mobile device. You could use FluorineFX (free) or webOrb on a webserver to send data back and forth to a database server if that were needed. If you build it with the Flashbuilder 4.6 mobile project template, it would work on a iPad, mac, windows pc, or android device as well. Since a pc touchscreen should use the same type of finger gestures as a mobile app, this might be a nice way to go. (I don't actually have a touchscreen on my pc, but it runs well with a mouse, so I'd assume it worked with gestures too).

Adobe.tv has lots of examples of building a mobile app project (Which also runs on a PC) and there is a Flashbuilder 4.6 free trial.

http://flex.org/